# IIS hosted Wcf service with assemby resolution is possible?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, hosting

Is it possible to load assemblies via assembly resolve event in iis hosted wcf service. I don't want load assemblies via GAC or bin folder. Is it possible? thanks.

Comment: so you want the implementation assembly to live in a "custom" location?

Comment: @brandon yes custom location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event, but what you might try is [using MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) to resolve actual implementation using a [DirectoryCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.aspx).

So your SVC code behind (or you can remove the code behind and point your SVC to a class in a separate assembly) would look something like this (untested). I've not tried this specific method, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't work.

```
public class YourServiceClass : YourServiceContract
{
    [Import]
    private IContract Implementation { get; set; }

    private DirectoryCatalog _directoryCatalog = null;
    private CompositionContainer _container = null;

    public YourServiceClass()
    {
        _directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(YourDirectoryPathHere);
        _container = new CompositionContainer(_directoryCatalog);
        _container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    //Operation
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Implementation.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

You could also move the MEF code to a base class if that makes sense. If you're new to MEF, here's a tutorial [using MEF with a DirectoryCatalog](http://brandonzeider.me/2010/microsoft-net/extensible-applications-with-mef/).